# Closing/terminating application programmatically

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

After showing the window and want to do some stuff and then close both window and python; what code should I use ?

```
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):     
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.showMaximized() 

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = mywindow()
    application.show()
    # !!!!! do some stuf and close application (including window)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You have `sys.exit()` in there, so it's unclear what you're asking. If the script is executed from the command line, that's where you'll return. If it's running as a standalone program, it will exit and close the window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the window then you must call the [`close()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close) method, which by default if there is no other window open, the application will close unless you set the [`quitOnLastWindowClosed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) qproperty to true.

```py
# ...
application.show()
# foo tasks
application.close()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If instead you want to force the application to close, you can use [`QCoreApplication::quit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) or [`QCoreApplication::exit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exit).

```py
# ...
application.show()
# foo tasks
QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```